# How to pass a variable from backend to frontend in tauri

Tags: rust, sveltekit, tauri

I have a Tauri app, with sveltekit as frontend.
In the backend, I have a Websocket that collects some data in a variable.
Now, I need to display this data in the frontend. I tried the `emit_all` event, and even something like this:

```rs
[...]   
 tauri::command::emit_all(
        tauri::Window::current(),
        "request",
        Some(json!({ "request": request })),
    )
    .expect("Failed to send request to frontend");
[...]
```

And the code doesn't even compile.
Is the approach wrong? I tried even other solutions (and I always have the listener in the frontend)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the shortest code I used that does what you want:

```rs
fn function<R: tauri::Runtime>(manager: &impl Manager<R>) {
    manager.emit_all("event", ()).unwrap();
}
```

This is how you use it on the javascript side:

```js
import { listen } from "@tauri-apps/api/event";

await listen("event", (event) => {})
```

In the payload I would recommend you use `serde_json` directly, as that's what Tauri uses. But unless you post the actual compilation problem, we cannot know exactly what's wrong.